# How do you find out the total size of the data in MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

How do you calculate the total size of the database in MySQL?

P.S. Total size in term of how much disk space is using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,370163,371130) has a pretty intense query... that will give you more than you need...:

```
SELECT s.schema_name, 
CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(t.data_length)+SUM(t.index_length)) /1024/1024,2),0.00)) total_size_in_MB, 
CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND(((SUM(t.data_length)+SUM(t.index_length))-SUM(t.data_free))/1024/1024,2),0.00)) data_used_IN_MB, 
CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(data_free)/1024/1024,2),0.00)) data_free_IN_MB, 
IFNULL(ROUND((((SUM(t.data_length)+SUM(t.index_length))-SUM(t.data_free))/((SUM(t.data_length)+SUM(t.index_length)))*100),2),0) pct_used, 
COUNT(table_name) total_tables 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA s 
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON s.schema_name = t.table_schema 
WHERE s.schema_name = 'abc' -- give your schema name 
GROUP BY s.schema_name 
ORDER BY pct_used DESC;
```

Comment: Which is effectively a formatted `SUM` of the `data_length` values in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for actual disk space usage what about just calculating the size of the mysql data directory using a filesystem utility like "du" ?

Comment: That shows you how much filesystem space is taken by files, but files can be partially empty.  Also there can be log files in the data dir, which are not part of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the information given by

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM dbname;
```

The `Data_length` column should be of interest.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Or if you need access within the context of a normal query, then the contents of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` tables can help. (See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html)

Comment: Thanks, is Data_length in byte?

Comment: Yes, it's in bytes.  But index_length is also important, since it can be as much or more as data_length.