# How to find total space used by specific user in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've read [total size of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011766/how-do-you-find-out-the-total-size-of-the-data-in-mysql-database), [determine space of a particular table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474591/how-can-you-determine-how-much-disk-space-a-particular-mysql-table-is-taking-up), etc., but am wondering, is it possible to find the total space a specific user in the table is using (like how GMail shows you how much total space you've used.)?

Say I have user_id 1 who has 100 private messages (not in a folder, simply in the db) and 10 file uploads (whose location are stored in the db). These are all in 3 separate tables, but they do take up MySQL space). Is it possible to create a query that gives me a total of all that space for that user?

Comment: If you can write a query for each table, put them together using `UNION`, and then put those in a subquery that you then aggregate using `SUM()`.

Comment: I may actually try this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "not really". You *can* add up the space in all the fields in all the tables used by the user. But is this really the amount of space used by the user?

Consider a table with only one record. The data needs to be somewhere. In databases, records are stored on pages, and a typical page size is 16k. So, regardless of how big or small the one record is, it will occupy at least 16k. Do you attribute all this to the user?

Just consider the size of the record. Sometimes, fields such as integers, floats, and doubles need to be aligned -- that is, start on 4-byte or 8-byte boundaries in the address space. This can leave holes in the record. Is this attributable to the user? Similarly, `varchar()` types have an overhead for storing the length and nullable columns have overhead for storing `NULL` flags. How do you attribute these?

The situation becomes more complicated when you start to add in indexes and blob and text types, which introduce other types of pages containing data.

And, often, you can delete all the records used by a user and release no free pages for the database to use. New records would go into the previously-used space, but only new records in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.
The following query will show you the space occupied by the entire `yourtable` table, but you can't filter it down to specific rows or conditions. This would mean it shows the space occupied by all the users.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS IN your_database LIKE 'yourtable';
```

What gmail shows you, it's physical space. The emails are stored on the server as files, not in a database. That's why you can determine how much space it's used.

One hard way would be to create a temporary table for that specific user and populate it with the exact records of that user, and using the query that I wrote above, see the entire size of that table. That would be the total amount of space occupied by a specific user. The value you're interested in is `data_length`.

Anyway, if you chose this method, think about the fact that it's very resource expensive and you should cache the result and don't count on getting this data on the fly (on real time).

Comment: That's what I figured. I don't want to store the data as a file, but perhaps there's a way I can restrict users otherwise.

Comment: Read the second part of my message. You can cache a user's quota and update it with that method once a day or after X data changes.